# PHP Rename() Removes Owner Attribute in Windows?

Tags: php, windows, file, file-rename

I am making use of PHP's `rename` function and I notice it removes the attribute **OWNER** in windows.

Does anyone know how to over come this? I need to keep the files previous attributes as well as permissions.

Thanks to anyone that can shed some light on this as the php docs didn't help me.

### Update

The files I am trying to rename are SQL Server Database files. (Extensions: .mdf and .ldf). I detach these databases from SQL Server and then I rename them with PHP. However, if the properties are viewed before and after. It initially has an attribute OWNER but then after renaming via PHP it does not even have an OWNER attribute!

> Windows 7, SQL Server 2008, PHP 5.3.0

Comment: Ah I still want this question answered as it is baffling but `copy` works and then `unlink` the old file.

Comment: Quick testing in my XP box shows it does keep ownership. Your issue may be related to underlying file system, script credentials or moving to another drive. Can you provide further details?

Comment: @Álvaro - I added a little more info. Anything else I should add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using the copy and unlink option, not ideal but it will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

Does chown() work on Windows? See

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php